# in my for loop .split() only works once

Tags: python, list, loops, csv, split

So I have this app. It records data from the accelerometer. Here's the format of the data. It's saved in a .csv file.

```
time, x, y, z
0.000000,0.064553,-0.046095,0.353776
```

Here's the variables declared at the top of my program.

```
length = sum(1 for line in open('couchDrop.csv'))
wholeList = [length]
timeList = [length]#holds a list of all the times
xList = [length]
yList = [length]
zList = [length]
```

I'm trying to create four lists; time, x, y, z.  Currently the entire data file is stored in one list. Each line in the list contains 4 numbers representing time, x, y, and z.  I need to split wholeList into the four different lists.  Here's the subroutine where this happens:

```
def easySplit():
    print "easySplit is go "
    for i in range (0, length):
        current = wholeList[i]
        current = current[:-2]  #gets rid of a symbol that may be messing tings up
        print current
        print i
        timeList[i], xList[i], yList[i], zList[i] = current.split(',')
        print timeList[i]
        print xList[i]
        print yList[i]
        print zList[i]
        print ""
```

Here's the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/william/Desktop/acceleration plotter/main.py", line 105, in          <module>
    main()
   File "/home/william/Desktop/acceleration plotter/main.py", line 28, in main
easySplit()
  File "/home/william/Desktop/acceleration plotter/main.py", line 86, in easySplit
timeList[i], xList[i], yList[i], zList[i] = current.split(',')
IndexError: list assignment index out of range`
```

Another weird thing is that my dot split seems to work fine the first time through the loop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For data manipulation like this, I'd recommend using Pandas. In one line, you can read the data from the CSV into a Dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("couchDrop.csv")
```

Then, you can easily select each column by name. You can manipulate the data as a `pd.Series` or manipulate as a `np.array` or convert to a list. For example:

```
x_list = list(df.x)
```

You can find more information about pandas at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html.

EDIT: The error with your original code is that syntax like `xList = [length]` does not create a list of length `length`. It creates a list of length one containing a single int element with the value of `length`.

Answer (score 0):

the code line `wholeList = [length]` doesnt create a list of length = `length`. It creates a list with only one element which is integer `length`, so if you were to `print(wholeList)` you will only see `[3]`
Since lists are mutable in python, you can just to wholeList =[] and keep appending elements to it. It doesnt have to be of specific length.

And when you do `current.split(',')` which is derived from wholeList, its trying to split only data available for first iteration i.e. `[3]`